Valgrind Invalid read write for all instance variables of the class
I have a class which have certain instance variables. I am getting random crashes when i run my application. Thinking memory corruption, I ran the application under valgrind, and I am able to narrow down the issue to one class.
The class is called GRETunnelInterface which inherits from base class as follows :
GRETunnelInterface --> VirtualInterface --> Interface
I segregated the steps to repro the issue, and noticed that the moment i instantiate GRETunnelInterface class, valgrind shows invalid read/writes for all instance variables which i try to read or write during the initialization of the class itself.
Class definition is below.
Things I cross-checked :
All instance variables of the base classes are initialised in constructors.
class GRETunnelInterface : public VirtualInterface {

private:
protected:
public:

uint32_t tunnel_id;
Interface *tunnel_src_intf;
uint32_t tunnel_src_ip;
uint32_t tunnel_dst_ip;
uint32_t lcl_ip;
uint8_t mask;
VirtualPort *virtual_port_intf;

enum GreTunnelConfigEnum
{
    GRE_TUNNEL_TUNNEL_ID_SET = 1,
    GRE_TUNNEL_SRC_INTF_SET = 2,
    GRE_TUNNEL_SRC_ADDR_SET = 4,
    GRE_TUNNEL_DST_ADDR_SET = 8,
    GRE_TUNNEL_OVLAY_IP_SET = 16,
    GRE_TUNNEL_ADMIN_SHUT_SET = 32
};

uint16_t config_flags;
GRETunnelInterface(uint32_t tunnel_id);
virtual ~GRETunnelInterface();
... other methods....
}

Valgrind Errors :
==906104== Invalid write of size 2
==906104==    at 0x144F68: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:961)
==906104==    by 0x129007: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
==906104==    by 0x1287F7: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)

==906104== Invalid read of size 2
==906104==    at 0x144F70: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:962)
==906104==    by 0x129007: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
==906104==    by 0x1287F7: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)

==906104== Invalid write of size 2
==906104==    at 0x144F80: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:962)
==906104==    by 0x129007: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)

. . . . 

You can see all valgrind errors ends up in the constructor of the class.
Pasting the constructor initialisation code of the class. Looks quite trivial, why would it lead to invalid read/writes.
GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(uint32_t tunnel_id)

: VirtualInterface(std::string("tunnel") + std::to_string(tunnel_id), INTF_TYPE_GRE_TUNNEL)
{

this->tunnel_id = tunnel_id;
this->config_flags = 0;
this->config_flags |= GRE_TUNNEL_TUNNEL_ID_SET;
this->tunnel_src_intf = NULL;
this->tunnel_src_ip = 0;
this->tunnel_dst_ip = 0;
this->lcl_ip = 0;
this->mask = 0;
this->virtual_port_intf = NULL;

}


VirtualInterface::VirtualInterface(std::string ifname, InterfaceType_t iftype)
: Interface(ifname, iftype)
{
}


Interface::Interface(std::string if_name, InterfaceType_t iftype)
{

this->if_name = if_name;
this->iftype = iftype;
this->config_ref_count = 0;
this->dynamic_ref_count = 0;
this->att_node = NULL;
memset(&this->log_info, 0, sizeof(this->log_info));
this->link = NULL;
this->is_up = true;
this->ifindex = get_new_ifindex();
this->cost = INTF_METRIC_DEFAULT;

this->pkt_recv = 0;
this->pkt_sent = 0;
this->xmit_pkt_dropped = 0;
this->recvd_pkt_dropped = 0;

this->l2_egress_acc_lst = NULL;
this->l2_ingress_acc_lst = NULL;

this->l3_ingress_acc_lst2 = NULL;
this->l3_egress_acc_lst2 = NULL;

this->isis_intf_info = NULL;
}

What could be possible reason for these valgrind errors. Every time I perform operation on application which involves read/write into instance variables of GRETunnelInterface class, more invalid read/write errors shows up which later translates into random application crash.
I hope C++ classes can embed C-structures but vice-versa is not true.
When I run the application, unless I instantiate GRETunnelInterface class, no valgrind errors are seen. So, issue is not somewhere else in the project I believe.
asagar@lima-default:~/tcpip_stack$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

Code which calls the GRETunnelInterface( ) constructor. My appln has CLI interface. So, this fn is invoked through CLI.
bool
gre_tunnel_create (node_t *node, uint16_t tunnel_id) {

Interface *tunnel;
byte intf_name[IF_NAME_SIZE];

snprintf ((char *)intf_name, IF_NAME_SIZE, "tunnel%d", tunnel_id);

tunnel = node_get_intf_by_name(node, (const char *)intf_name);

if (tunnel) {
    return false;
}

int empty_intf_slot = node_get_intf_available_slot(node);

if (empty_intf_slot < 0) {

    cprintf ("Error : No NIC slot available in a device\n");
    return false;
}

tunnel = new GRETunnelInterface(tunnel_id);

if (!tunnel ) {
    cprintf ("Error : GRE Tunnel creation failed\n");
    return false;
}

node->intf[empty_intf_slot] = tunnel;
tunnel->att_node = node;
tunnel->InterfaceLockStatic();
return true;
}

There is only one definition.  My appln represents a network topology where each node is a separate thread, so threads are isolated from each other completely.
Valgrind logs :
    ==30892== Thread 2:
    ==30892== Invalid write of size 2
    ==30892==    at 0x143E70: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:961)
    ==30892==    by 0x126FB3: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==  Address 0xad6d288 is 12 bytes after a block of size 188 alloc'd
    ==30892==    at 0x48859FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
    ==30892==    by 0x126F9B: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==
    ==30892== Invalid read of size 2
    ==30892==    at 0x143E78: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:962)
    ==30892==    by 0x126FB3: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==  Address 0xad6d288 is 12 bytes after a block of size 188 alloc'd
    ==30892==    at 0x48859FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
    ==30892==    by 0x126F9B: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==
    ==30892== Invalid write of size 2
    ==30892==    at 0x143E88: GRETunnelInterface::GRETunnelInterface(unsigned int) (Interface.cpp:962)
    ==30892==    by 0x126FB3: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==  Address 0xad6d288 is 12 bytes after a block of size 188 alloc'd
    ==30892==    at 0x48859FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
    ==30892==    by 0x126F9B: gre_tunnel_create(node_*, unsigned short) (gre.cpp:39)
    ==30892==    by 0x1267A3: gre_tunnel_config_handler(int, stack*, op_mode) (grecli.cpp:56)
    ==30892==    by 0x1135FB: task_cbk_handler_internal(event_dispatcher_*, void*, unsigned int) (cli_interface.c:47)
    ==30892==    by 0x13982F: event_dispatcher_thread(void*) (event_dispatcher.c:219)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D3597B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:447)
    ==30892==    by 0x4D9B7DB: thread_start (clone.S:79)
    ==30892==

E3

Please put the narrowed down parts in a [mre] so that we can compile it and analyse it properly

You may also want to mention what C++ version you are using. ... = NULL; looks like C++98.

Also which Valgrind version?

And how do you allocate the object of type GRETunnelInterface?

Adding the output from g++ --version to the question does not make your code into a [mre]. It also doesn't answer what C++ version you are using.

valgrind-3.22.0
tunnel = new GRETunnelInterface(tunnel_id);
@PaulFloyd

You need to edit your post with more information to get a proper answer. Show us the code where the object is allocated.
There are only a few things that could be going wrong.

This isn't the case. You could be using placement new with a memory block that is smaller than the size of the class.
You could have a "One Definition Rule" (ODR) violation. That means that you have more than one definition for your class. If you have one source file with the constructor and the full definition of the class then a second source file with the new expression and a second, smaller, definition of the class. I think that this is the most likely.
You have a threading issue and the memory gets deleted on a second thread between the first thread's operator new and constructor. Unlikely.

So here is what I think is happening.
// main.cpp
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
};

int main()
{
   Foo* f = new Foo;
   delete f;
}

and
// other.cpp
class Foo
{
   double d;
public:
   Foo();
};


Foo::Foo()
{  
   d = 0.0;
}

This gives
$ g++ -g -o test main.cpp other.cpp
$ valgrind -q ./test
==3583250== Invalid write of size 8
==3583250==    at 0x4011DC: Foo::Foo() (other.cpp:11)
==3583250==    by 0x401195: main (main.cpp:10)
==3583250==  Address 0x540f080 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==3583250==    at 0x403CF18: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:487)
==3583250==    by 0x40118A: main (main.cpp:10)

UPDATE:
Having looked briefly at the code, my next thought that this is a varation of point 2 above.
File gre.cpp contains the new expression (and needs to see the correct size of class GRETunnelInterface). File Interface.cpp contains the constructor.
Somehow I think that the size seen in gre.cppis too small. I see that the code contains several #pragma pack (push,1). So my next guess is that gre.cpp is seeing a packed version of the class but not Interface.cpp. A similar thing could happen with #define or typedef if the two files use different defines/typedefs for members of the class.

hmm, thnks for your time. I dont have multiple definitions of the same class. If you want to checkout the code, pls visit :  https://github.com/sachinites/tcpip_stack/blob/DCB/Interface/Interface.cpp
https://github.com/sachinites/tcpip_stack/blob/DCB/Interface/Interface.h
